# standards to describe Database Services

Tags: database, web-services, standards

WSDL (Web Service Description Language)   is a general description Language for describing web service.

Do you know a description language / standards, which are specially designed to describe Database Web services?

-Pankesh

Comment: What is a "Database web service"?

Comment: My notion of database web service is "A service, which stores data in persistent database and service have data access mechanism (such as query)".

Comment: @NevilleK : you can call "Database Web Service" as "storage service" also.

Comment: in that case, how is it different to a web service? Why couldn't you use WSDL to define it?

Comment: B'coz WSDL does not allow me to specify Query mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a 'Database Web Service' is, but a [***schema***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) is the rough equivalent of a WSDL for databases - although the 'language' used to describe the schema will vary between RDBMS vendors.

Comment: Thanks Widor for your reply. I define "Database Web Service" as it has operations and data access mechanism.